# keeping a listview value

Tags: android, listview

At me the screen is divided into 2 parts, in the left part is a brand list of the goods in the right at pressing a brand there is a list of the goods with a field for input of quantity, I need to implement saving of the entered data at transition between brands.I just can not figure out how to do it. Thanks

Comment: you should post what you've tried so far so others can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use like this: as **main_activity.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragmentBrandsList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.4" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flFragmentBrandsDetails"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.6" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**fragment_brands_list.xml**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/ivBrands"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

**fragment_brands_details.xml**

// your UI of the details of the Brands

**MainActivity.java** :  **onCreate()** method

```
fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentBrandsList, new BrandsListFragment());
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.flFragmentBrandsDetails, new BrandsListDetails());
fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
```

**BrandsListFragment.java**: **onCreateView()** method

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brands_list, container, false);

        brandsList = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.brandsList);
        ivBrands = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivBrands);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, brandsList);
        ivBrands.setAdapter(adapter);

        ivBrands.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                BrandsListDetails.setImageResource(position);
            }
        });

        return view;
```

**BrandsListDetails.java** : **onCreateView()** method

```
{
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_brands_details, container, false);   
return view;
}
public static void setImageResource(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                // Display First Brand Details
                break;
            case 1:
                // Display Second Brand Details
                break;
            case 2:
                // Display Third Brand Details
                break;

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I belive that you have an editText for the input.

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
        int count, int after) {

    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
      int before, int count) {
        String yourValueToSave=yourEditText.getText().ToString();
    }
});
```

This is one of the easiest way to do this. With this every time the user changes the value of the editText it will be saved in "yourValueToSave" variable.

This is the best i can do without a snippet of code or more details about what you tried already.